# CDN with Node.js SDK?

Tags: node.js, cdn

I wanna store my images using a CDN or any other static content hosting service.

One criterium is that they are supporting a Node.js SDK so I don't have to wrap the HTTP API myself in Node.js.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "they are supporting a Node SDK so I don't have to wrap the HTTP API myself"?

Comment: Some services have a HTTP API so you can make requests against it (PUT /users/1, GET /users/1 etc). Other libraries wraps this under a SDK for your language (node.js etc) so that you can do Service.createUser(1), Service.readUser(1) etc. I wonder if there are CDNs that are providing node.js specific SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Charlie Robbins' [node-cloudfiles](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-cloudfiles).. it uses [RackSpace CloudFiles](http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/files/api/cf-devguide-latest.pdf). There is also [Sunny.js](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/node-sunny) which uses Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage.